# Auto colour while replying emails

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client

There is a setting for picking up a new colour, each time we reply an email in Outlook 2010. I have enabled that option and can see different colours being picked each time I reply a long thread of emails.

However, if the colour is any shade of red (colour range), then I don't want this rule to apply. Is this possible?

Comment: Not with the standard rules, the only thing you can do is, when it is red, manually change it (or may be a complex macro would help).

Comment: There should be some way ? Maybe an external file can help some how ? I don't have any idea, but manually changing colour is the same thing like turning auto colour off and doing it manually every time.

Comment: The issue is 'any shade of red' may make this very difficult - what about maroon or pink (both contain red but are different colours). Can you also confirm you mean background colour of the email, and not categorizing.

Comment: With any shade of red, I meant we should be able to specify a colour range (based on hex code or whatever). And the colour is the text colour and not the background colour of email